# How to get the version of Spring Boot in the /info actuator endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

It's possible to include the version of Spring Boot in the banner.txt by adding `${spring-boot.version}`.

How can I do the same for the `/info` actuator endpoint?
I've tried adding both of the following to my application properties, but no luck:

- `info.app.spring-boot.version=${spring-boot.version}`
- `info.app.spring-boot.version=@spring-boot.version@`

The `/info` endpoint will print "${spring-boot.version}" (or "@spring-boot.version@" ), doesn't resolve the placeholder variable

My next idea was to create a Maven property for the Spring Boot version and reference it in the parent section like so

```xml
<properties>
    <spring.boot.version>1.5.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

But this didn't work because Maven resolves placeholder variables AFTER handling the `<parent>` section

### UPDATE

The following does work, but it's not ideal:

```java
@Component
public class MyInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {

        builder.withDetail("spring-boot.version", SpringBootVersion.getVersion());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't your updated solution not ideal? It returns exactly what you want... Else configure maven to process your properties file to replace the `@prop@`. However I would probably go for the `InfoContributor`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <additionalProperties>
      <spring-boot-version>${spring.boot.version}</spring-boot-version>
    </additionalProperties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You then don't need the app.info properties.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your update, an `InfoContributor` can be used to add this property based on the value in `SpringBootVersion`:

```java
@Component
public class SpringBootVersionInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {
    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        builder.withDetail("spring-boot.version", SpringBootVersion.getVersion());
    }
}
```

This seems a pretty solid idiomatic approach to adding this detail.